# Assigning non-geographic data to table in MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, table, update

I'm trying to update a non-georeferenced table (Table A) to make it georeferenced/mappable.  I'm trying to do this using a common set of data also found in a georeferenced table (Table B).

So both tables have one column which contains the same information.  This information is a list of sites/polygons.

Table B has one row for each site while Table A has many rows for each site.

I need to make Table A's list of sites georeferenced or add a georeferenced column.  For example, if row 1 in Table A contains the site "X" ID then assign that row to polygon "X" in the Map Window.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by joining the two tables.

Go to TABLE, SQL Select.

In the dialog select the two tables using the *Tables* dropdown list. Make sure the two table names are put into the *from Tables* field.

Now position the cursor in the *where Condition* field. Select the first ID column from the *Column* dropdown. Type an = or select it from the *Operators* dropdown and then select the ID column from the other table.

In the *Select Columns* field, you can either leave the * or select only some of the columns.

[image]

Now save the resulting query as a new table. You should when you open this copy see that each record have been assigned a polygon.

You might also want to check if your resulting table holds all the records from TABLEA.